# How to change schema in JAXB message?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I send JAXB-generated message (using WSDL and XSD):

```
   ...
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns28:getClientsDetailRequest ...>
         <ns28:ClientIdentifier>
            <ns12:id>123</ns12:id>
            <ns12:system>qwe</ns12:system>
            <ns12:type>asd</ns12:type>
         </ns28:ClientIdentifier>
         <ns28:entitySet>zxc</ns28:entitySet>
         <ns28:clientScope>rty</ns28:clientScope>
      </ns28:getClientsDetailRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   ...
```

But the scheme should be "tns" and "idn", like that:

```
   ....
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <tns:getClientsDetailRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tns:ClientIdentifier>
            <idn:id>123</idn:id>
            <idn:system>qwe</idn:system>
            <idn:type>asd</idn:type>
        </tns:ClientIdentifier>
        <tns:entitySet>zxc</tns:entitySet>
        <tns:clientScope>rty</tns:clientScope>
    </tns:getClientsDetailRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    ...
```

How can I change the scheme?

Comment: Why does it matter? It is only a reference to an xsd (basically an alias) the name shouldn't matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's not a reference to an xsd, it's a reference to a namespace, which may or may not be defined in an XSD.

Comment: I know it refers to a namespace which isn't anything more then a reference to a namespace but alas. Nonetheless it shouldn't matter if it is named ns1 or ns2 or ns3 as long as the namespace is the same.